# How to convert a string to a datetime object in python?

Tags: python, datetime

### *Application built with: Python and Angular*

I have a form that uses the following input to allow a user to insert a date:

```html
<input type="datetime-local" id="clubJoined" name="clubJoined" class="date-input" formControlName="clubJoined">
```

And in my python backend I convert this string object into a date object using the following:

```py
#   - Club Joined
"club_joined": datetime.datetime.strptime(request.form["clubJoined"], '%y-%m-%d %H:%M')
```

But this gives me a formatting error:

```
ValueError: time data '2011-01-01T23:36' does not match format '%y-%m-%d %H:%M'
```

So I added the `T` so that the conversation format looks like this:

```
#   - Club Joined
"club_joined": datetime.datetime.strptime(request.form["clubJoined"], '%y-%m-%dT%H:%M')
```

But this gave me the following error:

```
ValueError: time data '2011-01-01T23:36' does not match format '%y-%m-%dT%H:%M'
```

How do I format this correctly?

Comment: Please see the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-format-codes). The short answer is that `%y` is the format code for a two-digit year; `%Y` for a fully specified year.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct format is `"%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M"`

`%y` stands for two-digits year, [here](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/datetime/strftime) you can find full list of format options.

Comment: Thank you, that worked